# Container.DataItemIndex not working inside of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

For some reason in my code container.DateItemIndex is not returning any value in my code.

Here is my asp.net:

```
   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

<form id="form1" runat="server"> 
         <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
             AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
             EnableModelValidation="True" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" >

             <Columns>
                 <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ControlStyle-CssClass="savefile"/>
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                     ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="event_name" HeaderText="event_name" 
                     SortExpression="event_name" />

                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PDF">

           <ItemTemplate>

               <asp:Button ID="Button1" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' CommandName="DownloadFile" runat="server" Text="Button" />

            </ItemTemplate>

           <EditItemTemplate>

               <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /> // shown only in edit mode

           </EditItemTemplate>

          </asp:TemplateField>

             </Columns>
         </asp:GridView>
</form>
```

and my C# code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

    if (e.CommandName == "DownloadFile")
    {

        Label1.Text = e.CommandArgument.ToString();

    }

}
```

Why am i not getting any values from the  CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'

Comment: Are you rebinding the gridview on post-back, or are you using ViewState?

Answer (score 4):

Replace `CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'` with `CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItemIndex")%>'`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change button properties dynamicaly on [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx):

```
    void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
      {

        if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
          var button =  e.Row.FindControl("Button1");

          button.CommandArgument = e.Row.DataItemIndex;
          button.CommandName="DownloadFile";         
          button.Text="Button";
          // COLUMN_INDEX where button shoud be
          e.Row.Cells[COLUMN_INDEX].Controls.Add(button);
         }

      }
```

Comment: -1 This won't work because you need to get the reference of `Button1` with `GridViewRow.FindControl` instead of creating a new instance of `Button`.

Comment: This is still not a viable approach. `GridView.RowDataBound` is a bad place to add controls dynamically (unlike `RowCreated`) since it will only be called on databinding and not on every postback. But dynamical controls must be recreated on every postback. Apart from that it is unnecessary since it would work to just use the existing `Button`. He gets a reference by `var btn = e.Row.FindControl("Button1");`.

Answer (score 0):

Every once in a while you need to get the index of the row in a GridView that triggered an event. You can setup the CommandArgument to store the row’s index for use in your code behind. In the GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="myId" OnRowCommand=" gridView_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'
                    CommandName="Add" Text="Add" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Referencing in the code-behind:

```
protected void gridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Add")
    {
        int myId = (int)gridView.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one.....I did always like that.....

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SNo." >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Please read the question carefully, user is asking for getting DataItemIndex not setting it.